# Горизонтальный ScrollBar в QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

Как можно включить отображение горизонтального `ScrollBar` в `QTreeView` с фиксированной шириной при выходе названия ветки за границы view'шки?

Comment: Может `treeView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded)`?

Comment: @aleks.andr Не поможет. treeView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded‌​) показывает скролл-бар при превышении ширины столбца над шириной вьюпорта treeView. Мне же нужно, чтобы при разворачивании ветки с элементом с длинным названием автоматически ширина столбца подстраивалась под длину строки ветки.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, пока делаю так:
1. `QTreeView::setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded‌​‌​)`.
2. На `QTreeView` ставим фильтр событий. В нём при нажатии клавиши мыши по любому элементу дерева вызываем метод `QTreeView::resizeColumnToContents(int столбец)`.
3. Ширина столбца подстраивается под длину элемента. Если ширина столбца оказывается больше ширины вьюпорта `QTreeView`, автоматически появляется скролл-бар.
Оставлю здесь на всякий случай.